# Group_concat with added columns

Tags: mysql, group-by, group-concat

I got a query that works just fine:

```
SELECT Course, Period, Room, Location, TeacherId, GROUP_CONCAT(StudentId) as Students 
FROM cursosv2 
GROUP BY Course, Period, Room, Location, TeacherID;
```

What I want (maybe too basic) is in the resulting query to have a new column, like NEW COLUMN A with the joined values of period+room+'final'. But I keep getting exceptions. Dont know the real reason.

What am I trying...

```
SELECT Course, Period, Room, Period+' '+Room+' Final' as test, Location, TeacherId, GROUP_CONCAT(StudentId) as Students 
FROM cursosv2 
GROUP BY Course, Period, Room, Location, TeacherID;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also use concat for string concatenation (not  + ) and add to group by

```
 SELECT Course, Period, Room, concat( Period,' ',Room,' Final') as test, Location, TeacherId, GROUP_CONCAT(StudentId) as Students 

 FROM cursosv2 
 GROUP BY Course, Period, test, Room, Location, TeacherID;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CONCAT_WS to achieve that.

(' ', Column1, column2) AS column_name

```
SELECT Course, Period, Room, concat_ws(' ', Room, Period) AS roomperiod, Location, TeacherId, GROUP_CONCAT(StudentId) as Students FROM cursosv2 GROUP BY Course, Period, Room, Location, TeacherID;
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws

Comment: The separator should be a space.

Answer (score 0):

Use `concat` to concatenate instead of `+`. And add `test` to the `group by` clause:

```
SELECT Course, Period, Room, concat(Period,' ',Room,' Final') as test, 
       Location, TeacherId, GROUP_CONCAT(StudentId) as Students 
FROM cursosv2 
GROUP BY Course, Period, Room, test, Location, TeacherID;
```